# how to update and delete and add datas to db in mvc using entity framework and AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a code for creating an api for get method. table has property name and phonenumber.

```
           public ActionResult List()
    {
        DLL.Models.MyDatabaseContext context = new DLL.Models.MyDatabaseContext();
        var contactlist = context.ContactNumberTables.ToList();            
        return Json(contactlist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

how can i make actions for update and delete and create?
what changes should i change to get api?

Comment: that is a very basic question so you should take a look here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started ... also, for angularJs you should use web api controllers so take a look here: http://www.asp.net/single-page-application

Comment: this is too much, im just a starter, ur providing ,me the entire tutorial instead of giving a proper link.

Comment: that's because the answer for your question would be every single step in those tutorials, go to the get started on each of them, you have an example for a trivia app if I recall correctly, that's where you can see how the create/update/delete controller actions should look like.

Comment: i want to do it using api(angularjs)

Comment: just look at this lab, everything is already there: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/build-a-single-page-application-spa-with-aspnet-web-api-and-angularjs ... you have to understand what you are doing, and as I said before, answering to your question would be copying every single step in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These steps are not based on Rest api but based on normal MVC Controller.
Save into database like this:

AngularJS

```
$http({
    url: 'baseurl/controller/Post',
    method: 'POST',
    data: data
}).success(function(callback) {});
```

Controller

```
//Call this method as POST method
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Post(ContactNumberTable numberTable)
{
    //Please use the below line globally
    DLL.Models.MyDatabaseContext context = new DLL.Models.MyDatabaseContext();
    context.ContactNumberTables.Add(numberTable);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

That's how need to update data:

AngularJS

```
$http({
    url: 'baseurl/controller/Update',
    method: 'PUT',
    data: data
}).success(function(callback) {});
```

Controller

```
//Call this method as HttpPut or HttpPost
[HttpPut]
public ActionResult Update(ContactNumberTable numberTable)
{
    DLL.Models.MyDatabaseContext context = new DLL.Models.MyDatabaseContext();
    var existingTableNumber = context.ContactNumberTables.Find(numberTable.ContactNumberTableID); //Primary key
    existingTableNumber.UpdateField1 = numberTable.UpdateField1; //Assign all the properties which you want to update
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

And that's how we need to delete the data:

AngularJS

```
$http({
    url: 'baseurl/controller/Delete/' + id,
    method: 'DELETE',
}).success(function(callback) {});
```

Controller

```
//Call this method as HttpDelete like yoururl/Controller/Delete/1
[HttpDelete]
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    var numberTable = DLL.Models.MyDatabaseContext context = new DLL.Models.MyDatabaseContext();
    context.ContactNumberTables.Remove(numberTable);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```